# draggable Marker gmaps.js get latitude and longitude

Tags: jquery, google-maps, gmaps.js

I am using the Gmaps.js script.
I can not find how to get latitude and longitude if I move Marker with draggable option

```
map = new GMaps({
    div: '#map',
    lat: -24.836536,
    lng: -65.393051,
    draggable: true,
    dragend: function(e) {
     //get latitude and longitude?????
      alert('click 01');
    }
});

map.addMarker({
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333,
    title: 'Lima',
    draggable: true,
    dragend: function(e) {
      //get latitude and longitude?????
      alert('click 02');
    }
});
```

this is what I want to do, but with gmaps.js http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/examples/draggable.html

Gracias!!!!! 
Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solucionado

```
map.addMarker({

            //lat:  ﻿-24.788333333333,
            //lng: -65.410555555556,
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            draggable: true,
            dragend: function(event) {
                var lat = event.latLng.lat();
                var lng = event.latLng.lng();
                alert('draggable '+lat+" - "+ lng);

            },
            title: 'Marker #' + index,
            infoWindow: {
                content: content
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `google.maps.Map` is map.map, to get the center on drag use:

```
map.map.getCenter()
```

dragend event listener:

```
dragend: function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  document.getElementById('mapinfo').innerHTML = "map center=" + map.map.getCenter().toUrlValue(6);
}
```

The `google.maps.Marker` dragend event returns a google.maps.MouseEvent, to get its location, use

```
e.latLng
```

dragend event:

```
dragend: function(e) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "marker position=" + e.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvur81sg/)